# Run worker every time user connects to internet

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I want to sync with the server every time the user connects to the internet. So far I have been using WorkManager to do the job with 3-hour intervals and constraints requiring internet-connected. But it is missing the intervals where the device is connected to the internet but the work period is not reached. I want it to run every single time the user connected to the internet.

Below is the sample code I am using:

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()
    val work = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ExampleWorker>(3, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(UniqueWorkerTag,
    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, work)
```

I have gone through different pages and the only solution I find is to use Firebase JobScheduler but it is now deprecated.

Comment: There really isn't anything available anymore that will allow you to do this every time the device reconnects. the connectivity broadcast receiver does not work unless you register it in code which means you either need your app in the foreground or you need a foreground service running all the time and register it in there

Comment: WorkManager will defer work if your constraints are not met to a later time but it wont do it every time it reconnects

Comment: WorkManager is about Satisfied constraints and not an event. You have only triggers about changes for a URI. You should either use a BroadcastReseiver if it is possible or just register for Connectivity callback as part of constantly running Service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) ? You can register a [ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) to the connectivityManager. This callback will be triggered whenever the network status changes.

Here is a sample code:

1. In AndroidManifest.xml file, add

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

2. In your kotlin / java file:

```kotlin
package app.soumicslab.stackoverflow

import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Network
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Constants / Statics
    companion object {
        const val TAG: String = "MainActivity"
    }

    // Variables
    private lateinit var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager
    private lateinit var networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    private var isInternetAvailableForApiGte21: Boolean = false

    // Override methods
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(!this::connectivityManager.isInitialized) {
            connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            registerNetworkCallBackForApiGte21()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            unregisterNetworkCallBackForApiGte21()
        }
    }

    // Private methods

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun registerNetworkCallBackForApiGte21() {
        if(!this::networkCallback.isInitialized) {
            this.networkCallback = object: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                    super.onAvailable(network)
                    isInternetAvailableForApiGte21 = true
                    Log.e(TAG, "networkCallBack onAvailable")

                    // todo: <------Your worker code goes inside here-----

                }

                override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                    super.onLost(network)
                    isInternetAvailableForApiGte21 = false
                    Log.e(TAG, "networkCallBack onLost")
                }
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val looper: Looper = Looper.getMainLooper()
            val handler = Handler(looper)
            this.connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(this.networkCallback, handler)
        }else{
            this.connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(this.networkCallback)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun unregisterNetworkCallBackForApiGte21() {
        if(this::networkCallback.isInitialized) {
            this.connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this.networkCallback)
        }
    }

}
```

So after running this, I toogled Wi-Fi, mobile data. This is the output in Android Studio's Logcat:

```
2021-09-21 08:54:38.668 4008-4008/app.soumicslab.stackoverflow E/MainActivity: networkCallBack onAvailable
2021-09-21 08:54:43.284 4008-4008/app.soumicslab.stackoverflow E/MainActivity: networkCallBack onLost
2021-09-21 08:54:48.527 4008-4008/app.soumicslab.stackoverflow E/MainActivity: networkCallBack onAvailable
2021-09-21 08:54:52.782 4008-4008/app.soumicslab.stackoverflow E/MainActivity: networkCallBack onLost
2021-09-21 08:55:04.459 4008-4008/app.soumicslab.stackoverflow E/MainActivity: networkCallBack onAvailable
2021-09-21 08:55:06.685 4008-4008/app.soumicslab.stackoverflow E/MainActivity: networkCallBack onLost
2021-09-21 08:55:10.228 4008-4008/app.soumicslab.stackoverflow E/MainActivity: networkCallBack onAvailable
... ... ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Qazi Fahim Farhan, but I want to look into the solution where the backend can sync regardless of the app usage, like a service. I guess the only way forward is to use Broadcast Reciever.